# individual comboboxes in each cell of a jtable (rookie)

Tags: java, jtable, jcombobox

Today I did a simple student / course selection database. 
Everything works fine so far.

Now I want to implement a graphical representation. I decided to use a JTable (wahltabelle) where each column is a course and each row a student.

There a different ways how a student can visit a course. That’s why I want a Combobox in each cell. The currently selected value represents the student’s current selection and can be changed by the course manager.

The values are loaded and stored from / to a database. 
Unfortunately I didn’t find out how to represent an individual combobox in each cell of a table.  Therefore I currently have a String representation of my comboboxes.

I know that I can easily change the default cell editor for a complete column. But unfortunately I’m not sure how to do that for a individual cell. 
Do I have to write my own cellRenderer?

```
public void addWahldata(List<Fach> faecher)
    {
        Vector head = new Vector<>();
        head.add("");
        for(Fach aktuell : faecher)
        {
            head.add(aktuell.getBezeichner());
        }


        Vector data = new Vector<>();

        wahltabelle.setModel(new DefaultTableModel(data, head));
        Vector rowx = new Vector<>();
        rowx.add("");

        JComboBox temp= null;
        for (int i=1; i<wahltabelle.getColumnCount(); i++)
        {

            JComboBox cb = new AbiMoeglichkeitenGetter().getAbiMoeglichkeiten(wahltabelle.getColumnName(i));
            temp = cb;
            rowx.add(cb);
        }
        data.add(rowx);
        wahltabelle.setModel(new DefaultTableModel(data, head));


    }
```

Thanks for any explanation.